# TypeError Involving Addition

Tags: python

## One-Time Pad (Polyalphabetic Sustitution Cipher)

```
import pyperclip, os.path

LETTERS = r""" !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY
Z[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~"""

def main():
    message = """Alan Mathison Turing was a British mathematician,
logician, cryptanalyst, and computer scientist. He was highly influential in
the development of computer science, providing a formalisation of the concepts
of "algorithm" and "computation" with the Turing machine."""
    mode = 'encrypt'
    key = os.urandom(len(message))
    if mode == 'encrypt':
        translated = encryptMessage(key, message)
    elif mode == 'decrypt':
        translated = decryptMessage(key, message)

    print('%sed message:' % (mode.title()))
    print(translated)
    pyperclip.copy(translated)
    print()

    print('The message has been copied to the clipboard.')

def encryptMessage(key, message):
    return translateMessage(key, message, 'encrypt')


def decryptMessage(key, message):
    return translateMessage(key, message, 'decrypt')


def translateMessage(key, message, mode):
    translated = [] # this is gonna store the message string

    keyIndex = 0
    key = key.upper()

    for symbol in message:
        num = LETTERS.find(symbol.upper())
        if num != -1: # -1 means symbol.upper() was not found in LETTERS
            if mode == 'encrypt':
                num += LETTERS.find(key[keyIndex]) # Add if encrypting
            elif mode == 'decrypt':
                num -= LETTERS.find(key[keyIndex]) # Subract if decrypting

            num %= len(LETTERS) # Handle the wrap-around

            # Add the encrypted/decrypted symbol to the end of translated
            if symbol.isupper():
                translated.append(LETTERS[num])
            elif symbol.islower():
                translated.append(LETTERS[num].lower())

            keyIndex += 1 # Move to  the next letter in the key
            if keyIndex == len(key):
                keyIndex = 0
        else:
            # The symbol was not is LETTERS, so add it to translated as it is
            translated.append(symbol)

    return ''.join(translated)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am creating a program that is commonly known as the One-Time Pad Cipher, but when I run the program I get the Error:

```
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly*.
```

The program stops on line 70:

```
num += LETTERS.find(key[keyIndex]) # Add if encrypting
```

How can I fix this?

Note: I am aware of many other issues that plague my code.

Comment: Possible change it to EITHER `num += str(LETTERS.find(key[keyIndex]))` OR `num += '{}'.format(LETTERS.find(key[keyIndex]))`

Comment: Incidentally, a OTP can be implemented quite more compactly like: `print ''.join(chr(ord(x) ^ ord(y)) for x, y in izip(message, key))` (assuming a `from itertools import *`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `key[keyIndex]` is not a string. The `string.find` method only accepts a string.

This program works just fine AS IS in python 2.7, but in python 3.2 this is what is causing the issue.

## Solution A

Wrap `key[keyIndex]` in a `str()`.

```
if mode == 'encrypt':
    num += LETTERS.find(str(key[keyIndex]))
elif mode == 'decrypt':
    num -= LETTERS.find(str(key[keyIndex]))
```

## Solution B

You could even make a function to make life easier.

```
def findKeyValue(alphabet, key, index):
    return alphabet.find(key[index].__str__())
```

Then...

```
if mode == 'encrypt':
    num += findKeyValue(LETTERS, key, keyIndex)
elif mode == 'decrypt':
    num -= findKeyValue(LETTERS, key, keyIndex)
```

Comment: Hey Mr.Polywhirl, I tried both of your answers and I got the same error: TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly

Comment: Did you get an error on line 72 as well, because you have to do the same thing

Comment: I didn't get to that part of the code. The error comes on line 70. Also I tried doing the same thing for both lines 70 and 72. still getting error

Comment: @JaiminN: I found the issue. I ran this with python32.

Answer (score 0):

change the if-else condition from:

```
            if mode == 'encrypt':
                num += LETTERS.find(key[keyIndex]) # Add if encrypting
            elif mode == 'decrypt':
                num -= LETTERS.find(key[keyIndex]) # Subract if decrypting
```

to

```
            if mode == 'encrypt':
                num += int(LETTERS.find(key[keyIndex])) # Add if encrypting
            elif mode == 'decrypt':
                num -= int(LETTERS.find(key[keyIndex])) # Subract if decrypting
```

This is required as `num` is of type `int` and the `find()` on `LETTERS` is returning `str` in your program.